# mongodb insert and return id with REST API

Tags: mongodb, mlab

New to Mongodb,trying to get _id after mongodb insert without a round trip.

```
$.ajax( { url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/xxx/collections/xx?apiKey=xxx",
          data: JSON.stringify( [ { "x" : 2,"c1" : 34,"c2" : getUrlVars()["c2"]} ] ),
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json" } );
```

Thanks

edit: Solved buy removing square bracers  `JSON.stringify( { "x" : 2,"c1" : 34,"c2" : getUrlVars()["c2"]} )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the _id of the object without waiting for a response because the _id is generated on the server. You need to attach a success call to your request. The id is actually returned as a $oid member within an _id object.

This is assuming you are using $.ajax to make the request and the MongoLab REST API as documented at http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb

For example:

```
$.ajax( { url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/xxx/collections/xx?apiKey=xxx',
          data: JSON.stringify( {"x" : 1 } ),
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json"}
      ).success(function(returnedData) {
          alert(returnedData._id["$oid"]);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

What REST API are you using? MongoDB does not ship with a REST API that does what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using one provided with mongolab [link](http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

According to the MongoLab REST API docs, the square braces are for inserting multiple docs at a time. For a single document, you simply need to JSON.Stringify a single valid JSON (BSON) document.